# Can you freeze flyouts from moving for easier troubleshooting?

Tags: css, debugging, drop-down-menu, google-chrome-devtools, flyout

I am trying to troubleshoot a ul li width issue, but every time I go to the chrome inspector the flyout goes away (because I'm no longer hovering). Is there an easier way to freeze the flyout so i can go to the inspector and inspect that ul li?

Thanks!
Corey

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's inspector has options to toggle a hover state on and off. In the sidebar, if you are on the 'Styles' tab, in the top right is an icon that looks like a little dotted box with a mouse over it. Click that and then toggle the states on or off as you please.

Just make sure you have the element that has the hover state selected before doing this.

[image]